# how i can fetch the Tabs ID dynamically of jquery tab by using foreach loop in php OOP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, oop

I have a category table and subcategory table in my database. I'm trying to display the "category" title as the tab and the "subcategory" name as my tab content.

I have try to find the solution on google but not found any relevant solution.

Category in Tab

```
 <div class="product-category">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <?php $sql = "select * from category order by category_name asc";
       $category = Category::find_by_sql($sql);  
           foreach($category as $cat){
                ?>
<li>
<a class="small menu-icons clothing" href="#<?php echo $cat->id; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-shirtsinbulk"></i><?php echo $cat->category_name; ?></a>
</li>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Subcategory in Tab Content

```
 <div class="product-contant clearfix">
     <div class="product-block clearfix">
      <div class="tab-content">
       <?php $category = $cat->id;  
       $sql = "select * from sub_category where cat_id='$category' order by subcategory_name asc";
     $subcategory  =  Subcategory::find_by_sql($sql);                               
    foreach($subcategory as $subcat){
                                    ?>
     <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="<?php echo $subcat->cat_id; ?>">
        <div class="item-block clearfix">
      <div class="product-item">
    <ul class="products-row">
       <li class="image-block">
       <a href="#"><span><img src="images/products/women/clothing/products-img-6.jpg" alt="" /></span></a>
     </li>
       <li class="products-details">
       <a href="#"> <?php echo $subcat->subcategory_name; ?> </a>
          <span>$1600</span>
         </li>
         </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
                 </div>
                  <?php } ?>
                     </div>
                      </div>
</div>
```

I did not get subcategory name by category id

Comment: please specify have you got any error

Comment: Subcategory data fetch should be inside category foreach loop.

Comment: ok i will try to add subcategory in category foreach loop

Comment: if i add subcategory into category loop it change the whole style of tab

Comment: this is image link of tab https://unsee.cc/1d942237/ check please

Answer (score 0):

Please check my updated code

for category

```
<div class="product-category">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <?php $sql = "select * from category order by category_name asc"; //use join for both the table
       $category = Category::find_by_sql($sql);  
           foreach($category as $cat){
                ?>
<li>
<a class="small menu-icons clothing" href="#<?php echo $cat->id; ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-shirtsinbulk"></i><?php echo $cat->category_name; ?></a>
</li>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

for sub category

```
 <div class="product-contant clearfix">
    <div class="product-block clearfix">
      <div class="tab-content">
       <?php
       // $category = $cat->id;  
     //   $sql = "select * from sub_category where cat_id='$category' order by subcategory_name asc";
     // $subcategory  =  Subcategory::find_by_sql($sql);                               
    foreach($category as $cat){?>
       <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="<?php echo $cat->id; ?>">
          <div class="item-block clearfix">
            <div class="product-item">
               <ul class="products-row">
                 <li class="image-block">
                  <a href="#"><span><img src="images/products/women/clothing/products-img-6.jpg" alt="" /></span></a>
                </li>
                 <li class="products-details">
                    <a href="#"> <?php echo $cat->subcategory_name; ?> </a>
                    <span>$1600</span>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still shows nothing u can the image of tab  unsee.cc/1d942237

Comment: please check you subcategory query result then pass in to tab

Comment: i checked with var_dump it gives array(0) { } that it not getting any value from query

Comment: put your all subcategory code inside category foreach loop

Comment: like how can u help me because i tried it changes the whole style of tab

Comment: please refer this url https://www.phpzag.com/create-dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-with-php-mysql/

Comment: i'm using php oops is there any way so u can help me in this question because i have to submit my project this week

Comment: this is how my tabs looks check the image url https://unsee.cc/21d518ea/

Comment: have u seen image of tab which comment already please check the image

Comment: it echo all subcategory in a single cloumn not catgeory wise and where is subcategory_name

Comment: when it i refresh the page all subcategory name comes in single column but after click on category name it echo subcategory name by category id how to fix this problem

Comment: help me i'm waiting for ur rply

Comment: when i refresh it active all tab content at same time

Comment: have you seen my comment  //use join for both the table. means did you use joins for category or subcategory

Comment: i saw ur comment which parameter i used in join